# OBS Studio: временная шкала и планировщик

Tags: видео, obs

Есть ли модуль для запуска по планировщику источников и их смена? Временная шкала для OBS Studio ?

Comment: Опиши поподробнее пример того, как ты это собираешься использовать.

Comment: Obs-studio это не редактор видео. А броадкастер и мультиплексор. Поэтому шкалы времени там нет. Насчёт планировщика заданий не знаю, интересно было бы узнать есть ли такое?